# Batch Class error

Tags: apex, error

hello i have written below batch class but when its running its giving an error : System.StringException: Invalid id: u.id at line number 16

```
global class batchleadUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    User u = [select Id from User where Profile.Name='System Administrator' Limit 1];

        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Status ,OwnerId  FROM Lead WHERE Status != \'Closed - Converted\' AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Lead> scope)
    {
         for(Lead le : scope)
         {
             le.OwnerId = 'u.Id'  ;            
         }
         update scope;
    }   
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
    }
}
```

can any one help me by telling what i did wrong . will be of great help 
Thanks all

i fixed the code now but my test class is covering only 44% can any one help me with this

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
  private class batchleadUpdate_Test { 

static testMethod void batchleadUpdate_TestMethod (){
     Profile prof = [select id from profile where name='system Administrator'];
     User usr = new User(alias = 'usr', email='us.name@vmail.com',
                emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='lstname',
                timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',
                languagelocalekey='en_US',
                localesidkey='en_US', profileid = prof.Id,
                username='testuser128@testorg.com');
                insert usr;

          Lead lead=new Lead(LastName='Doe',FirstName='John',Company='Test',Status='Open');
insert lead;  
Lead ledRec1 = [SELECT Id,Name,Status,OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Status != 'Closed - Converted' limit 1 ];

   ledRec1.OwnerId = usr.Id;
   update ledRec1 ;
   Test.StartTest();

   batchleadUpdate objBatch = new batchleadUpdate();
   ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(objBatch);
   Test.StopTest();
  }
}
```

Comment: `'u.Id'` is a string, needs to be an Id - also, how are you hoping that `u` will be in scope in your execute method when it looks like you've declared it in your start method?

Comment: i am new to apex coding can you help me with this . i wanted to update le.ownerid with users id

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you familiar with variable scope though? You've declared a variable in one method and then tried to use it (albeit between single quotes) in another. Your query to `User` would probably better suited in your `execute` method so that your statement `le.OwnerId = u.Id` can access it.

Comment: you want to update all the Leads.ownerId in `scope` with the userId of some Sysad?  That is what the code/comment suggests. Please update your post to state your business problem more precisely

Comment: Yes user should be in Execute method . its working now. and in my code i am updating the owner id of leads which are created before 30 days and status is Not Closed - Converted .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because of the line `le.OwnerId = 'u.Id';`. You are trying to save a String to an OwnerId field. You are also querying the User field in the `start` method rather than the `execute` method. Have a look at the code below

```
global class batchleadUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Status ,OwnerId  FROM Lead WHERE Status != \'Closed - Converted\' AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Lead> scope) { 
         User u = [select Id from User where Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' Limit :1];
         for(Lead le : scope) {
             le.OwnerId = u.Id;            
         }
         update scope;
    }   
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barcotter , 
i made the changes already and its working

Comment: Bu ti am having problem with the test class . i am getting only 44% code coverage can you see and help if what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, if you create a new question with the batch class and also the test class Im sure we could help.

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: Hello Barcotter, below is the link for my question
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51197/code-coverage-for-the-test-class