# code coverage for the test class

Tags: unit-test, batch

i have a batch class which i am scheduling for run. and i have a test class for the batch class.

the batch class is working fine . but the code coverage is 44% .

important note: when the batch class is run and if it processes any data then the code coverage is going to 100% and if it don't process any then its dropping to 44%

My Batch Class :

```
global class batchleadUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Status ,OwnerId  FROM Lead WHERE Status != \'Closed - Converted\' AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Lead> scope)
    {
        User u = [select Id from User where Profile.Name='System Administrator' Limit 1];

         for(Lead le : scope)
         {
             le.OwnerId = u.Id  ;            
         }
         update scope;
    }   
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
    }
}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
  private class batchleadUpdate_Test { 

static testMethod void batchleadUpdate_TestMethod (){
     Profile prof = [select id from profile where name='system Administrator'];
     User usr = new User(alias = 'usr', email='us.name@vmail.com',
                emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='lstname',
                timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',
                languagelocalekey='en_US',
                localesidkey='en_US', profileid = prof.Id,
                username='testuser128@testorg.com');
                insert usr;

          Lead lead=new Lead(LastName='Doe',FirstName='John',Company='Test',Status='Open');
insert lead;  
Lead ledRec1 = [SELECT Id,Name,Status,OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Status != 'Closed - Converted' limit 1 ];

   ledRec1.OwnerId = usr.Id;
   update ledRec1 ;
   Test.StartTest();

   batchleadUpdate objBatch = new batchleadUpdate();
   ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(objBatch);
   Test.StopTest();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you incorporating test data into your Apex tests? If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Generating_and_Loading_Representative_Test_Data_for_Salesforce_and_Force.com_Orgs), it covers different methods for generating test data. I've just started exploring [SmartFactory](http://developer.force.com/projectpage?id=a063000000Db0CSAAZ), too.

Comment: Is your query returning anything?

Comment: NO becuase i dont have any date meeting this condition its a new org so i don't have a past data

Comment: if i can insert a lead which will have a created date meeting this condition then the update will cover but i don't know how to do this .

Comment: When your inserting the Lead can you just put `CreatedDate = system.today()` ..   Zayne was right, you have to treat your test class like your creating a record manually

Comment: i tried this and it is giving me an error Field is not writeable: Lead.CreatedDate

Comment: put in System.debugs and see what is getting returned in your class and test class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to generate testdata where the createdDate < today, you have to use JSON.deserialize (similarly, if you want to generate test leads with a convertedDate other than today.

This solution is outlined [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/49317/2602) for convertedDates and below for createdDate. Props to @sfdcfox for the original solution.

```
Lead [] lList = (Lead[]) JSON.deserialize(
    '[{"lastname" : "foo", "company" : "bar", "CreatedDate" : "2005-01-01"}]',List<Lead>.class);
insert lList;
```

Comment: Hey Crop,
thanks a tone its worked and the test class is now 100% . amazing

Comment: Great answer. You should create a new question titled something like **How do I set CreatedDate in unit tests?** and add that as the answer so that it is easier for other people to find. I assume the same holds true for LastModifiedDate

Comment: there was a long discussion about this here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/62/unit-testing-code-which-has-logic-around-the-createddate . I was kind of surprised myself that the DML would work as that discussion said it wouldn't